# Android large-sized emulator produces regular size application in center of screen

Tags: android, graphics, emulation, resolution

I always used the standard emulator when testing and thought it was about time to see what it looked like in a higher res/density setting. I ran my application using WVGA854 which has a density of 240 (rather than the 160 I usually used). The result is my application sitting as its old size in the center of the screen. I don't specifically hardcode the application size anywhere that would produce this (except for background images, but there are other things like x,y positions that are still limited by the old size). What gives? I move over the high res images into the correct folders but it still appears to be forcing my app to a smaller size? The background below is set to 854 width in the HDPI (and MDPI folder) but it is still cutting it off? Using a surfaceView to draw the bitmaps.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`<supports-screens>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) to your manifest, saying that you support large screens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll give this a shot tomorrow and update accordingly. Cheers.